# Find and concatenate lines using sed

Tags: shell, unix

I have a struct blocks within a long c file

```
struct node {
   int val;
   struct node *next;
};
```

How do I use the sed function to find this struct block and convert it into one line. So it looks like this:

```
struct node {   int val;   struct node *next;};
```

Thanks in advance

---

My input is this:

```
struct node {
   int val;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct {
   int numer;
   int denom;
} Rational;

int main()
{
struct node head;
Rational half, *newf = malloc(sizeof(Rational));

head = (struct node){ 5, NULL };
half = (Rational){ 1, 2 };
*newf = (Rational){ 2, 3 };
}
```

My output is :

```
struct node { int val; struct node *next;};

typedef struct { int numer; int denom;} Rational;int main(){struct node head;Rational  half, *newf = malloc(sizeof(Rational));head = (struct node){ 5, NULL };
half = (Rational){ 1, 2 };
*newf = (Rational){ 2, 3 };
}
```

I only want the struct node: `struct node { int val; struct node *next;};`
and the typedef struct: `typedef struct { int numer; int denom;} Rational;`
to be in one line. However int main() is being appended to the end of Rational;

I want the stuff in the main function to remain as it is.

Comment: You should show us what you've got that is producing the wrong output.  It's likely from what you describe that you aren't quite being careful enough with either the beginning or the end of the range of lines to be processed.  But sed will be hard-pressed to handle all possible variant layouts of the code.  Why do you want to do this flattening, anyway?  The code will be less readable.

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
sed '/struct[^(){]*{/{:l N;s/\n//;/}[^}]*;/!t l;s/  */ /g}' input.c
```

When `sed` sees a struct definition (`/struct[^{]*{/`), it will read lines until a `};` is seen on a line (`:l N;s/\n//;/[}];/!t l;`) while also removing newlines. When it matches `};` it removes extra spaces (`;s/  */ /g`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question: How do I make two extra copies of this line. So I would have two lines of "struct node {   int val;   struct node *next;};" right below the first...Thanks again you saved me 5 hours of research!

Comment: you can add a `p` just before the last curly: `...s/  */ /g;p}`

Comment: When I try to run the command above I get the error: "t: Event not found."
Can you help me out here? Thanks

Comment: Ignore my previous comment I was using TC shell rather than Bourne shell.

Comment: I am having trouble posting code in the reply section..I will just answer my own question to post up the problem

Comment: Could you check out my question below?...I am kind of new to this site. I will update the answer next time :)

Comment: No I am not familiar with that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Hello perreal...so when I used your line it works when the structs are only defined as shown above(that is using structure tag). But I would like to do the same when they are defined using structure types(using typedef). So I would like both "struct name {blah...blah}; and typedef struct { blah..blah} name; to be in one line and everything else to stay the same. Perhaps we need to do two passes to get this to happen. Thanks a lot for helping!